# jQuery get count value of console log with duplicate value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to count in `console.log` for each duplicate value.

[image]

As you can see above image, I need to get the count of true and false for each.

```
2 false
1 true
2 false
1 true
2 false
1 true
```

My code so far

```
 console.log(document.getElementById("lights").checked);
```

Is it possible to get it or if any another way without using console.log will be better?

Comment: A photo of the console uploaded and re-hosted on SO, yet no code...

Answer (score 0):

You're clearing using a loop, or repeated events, or similar. Simply keep track. Declare counters somewhere they'll be accessible to the place where that `console.log` is, but outside whatever loop or event handler it's in:

```
var trueCount = 0;
var falseCount = 0;
```

...and then in place of your `console.log`:

```
if (document.getElementById("lights").checked) {
    ++trueCount;
} else {
    ++falseCount;
}
```